# Xamarin.Mac/Cocoa equivalent of Window Loaded event?

Tags: c#, macos, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I'm working on my first Xamarin.Mac application to write a mac version of an existing WPF application. I am basing it off what I read in the ["Hello, Mac" documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/getting_started/hello%2C_mac/).

I have a couple of places where I would like to do things in response to the window being loaded. In WPF I would just attach an event handler to the window's Loaded event and be done with it.

What is the equivalent of that in Xamarin.Mac with a Cocoa window? Or is there  a better pattern to use? I see the various Did* events on the Window and WindowController classes, but there's no "DidLoaded" event or anything that seems similar.

I don't want to do it in the constructor because they might take a while and I don't want to prevent the window from showing - I want the window to be there first and then I start these things.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 2):

From that same guide, you should add this override to your MainWindow class.

```
public override void AwakeFromNib ()
{
    base.AwakeFromNib ();
    // enter code here
}
```

> We need to use AwakeFromNib, instead of another method such as
>   Initialize, because AwakeFromNib is called after the OS has loaded and
>   instantiated the User Interface from the .xib file. If we tried to
>   access the label control before the .xib file has been fully loaded
>   and instantiated, we’d get a NullReferenceException error because the
>   label control would not be created yet.